# enable or disable textbox inside gridview based on combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My requirement enable or disable a textbox inside a gridview based on the value selected in a combobox inside the same datagrid.Is there any value changed event for combo box inside a gridview?

Comment: It should still have the regular "selected index changed" event, even inside a gridview. Do you need more than that?

Answer (score 0):

the gridview in win form toolbox has some events, first that you can use to handle is ***CellValueChanged*** using this event you can get current selected value from any control, another way is to handle SelectedIndexChanged of combo

the source code that you need to handle combobox selection change in grid view is a bit different, the below code shows the process:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Control is ComboBox)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
    }
}

private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress;
    var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[0];
    //HERE YOU SHOULD DISABLE OR ENABLE TEXTBOX
}
```